# а в их числе был и российский император Николай II, и король Португалии Мануэль. Нужна ли запятая перед вторым союзом «и»?

Tags: пунктуация

а в их числе был и российский император Николай II, и король Португалии Мануэль

Answer (score 2):

Союз при однородных членах повторяется - нужна.